# WPF DataGrid won't update after code behind change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

Ok guys, So i have a Datagrid that gets refreshed with data from a dropdown from within the viewmodel. Everything works fine. I recently had to make a change that involved the DatagridColumnHeader click. Only thing i could think was to handle it this way and that was using the codebehind :(.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click" />
                </Style>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

and in the code behind handled that event. Now in the code behind I am making changes to the Datagrid

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader col = (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader)sender;
            ObservableCollection<tbMain> dc = (ObservableCollection<tbMain>)m_DataGrid.DataContext;
ObservableCollection<tbMain> sortedNewId = new ObservableCollection<tbMain>();

m_DataGrid.ItemsSource = sortedNewId;
m_DataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Now all that code works and refreshes my DataGrid fine, but I seem to have broke the binding between the viewmodel and DataGrid because now when I select something from the dropdown it no longer updates the grid with the new data until I click the header of the DataGrid. Any idea guys???

Comment: Why do you change the ItemsSource of your data grid to a new collection, instead of using the collection that is being provided by your view model? (Sorting should not require changing the ItemsSource.)

Comment: Try to remove the `Items.Refresh()`. That may be causing some issues since it should refresh anyway when you set the `ItemsSource`. Another thing to try is to actually pass your new collection in the `DataGrid.SetBinding(...) method`

Comment: @elgonzo the reason i do that is because otherwise my datagrid doesnt display the sorted data in ascending or descending order.

Comment: @bewilderedprogrammer, for sorting you might look into the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView method and the ICollectionView object it returns -- which will you allow to control sorting. However, this approach has one drawback: if you have multiple DataGrids (or ItemsControls) in your GUI, manipulating that CollectionView will possibly affect many or all of those ItemControls (it depends...). Continued...

Comment: ...(cont'd.) If you want to make sure that you control sorting only for the specific DataGrid, instantiate an **CollectionView** or **ListCollectionView** with the items list from your view model and assign this CollectionView to the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid. You will then use that CollectionView object to control sorting of your DataGrid (and only that DataGrid alone). That way, you won't mess around with the items list and the bindings just to get dynamic sorting behaviour for your datagrid. If it is that what you are looking for, let me know and i will put it as answer...

Comment: Alternatively, if your tbMain type is a sufficiently simple data type, sorting can also be entirely controlled through the DataGridColumn properties **SortDirection** and **SortMemberPath** without needing to deal with a CollectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are changing DataGrid's Items Source from Binding Expression (which notifies datagrid that source has been updated) to plain reference to collection, thereby removing updating logic.
You should change source collection, not Items Source. You could use CollectionView as source of binding expression for sorting by adding SortDescriptions to CollectionView and invoking Refresh on it